# List methods only in a module?

Tags: ruby

I wonder how one can list all methods in a module, but not including inherited methods.

eg.

```
module Software
  def exit
    puts "exited"
  end
end

puts Software.methods
```

Will list not only exit, but all inherited methods.

Is is possible to just list exit?

Thanks

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Actually `Software.methods` will *not* list `exit`. `Software.instance_methods` will list `exit` as well as any inherited methods (which in this case is nothing because modules don't inherit any methods unless you include another module). `Software.instance_methods(false)` will only list methods defined in `Software`.

Answer (score 36):

```
Software.public_instance_methods
```

seems to work for your example.

Comment: `Software.private_instance_methods` for private ones.